# Transactions for In App Purchases are not going through on some devices

Tags: ios, swift

I have been testing my In-App Purchases on two devices: an iPhone 11 Pro and an iPad Air (both IOS 13). On the iPad, when I try to buy the in app purchase, I would be asked to enter in my Apple ID and password, but when I try to buy it on my phone, nothing happens. Both devices are using the same sandbox account. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Here is the code for my in app purchase:

```
var product: SKProduct?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        buyButton.isEnabled = false
        buyButton.alpha = 0.5
        
        
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUnlimited") == false {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            getPurchaseInfo(productIDs: [productID])
        }
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func buy() {
        
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product!)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
    
    
    
    func getPurchaseInfo(productIDs: [String]) {
        
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
            
        }
        else {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In-App Purchases in your settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    // checks if product exists:
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        
        let products = response.products
        
        if products.count != 0 {
            
            product = products[0]
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.buyButton.isEnabled = true
                self.buyButton.alpha = 1
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Not Found", message: "Please make sure that you are connected to the Internet.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        let invalids = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
        
        for product in invalids {
            print("product not found: \(product)")
        }
        
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        
        for transaction in transactions {
            
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                self.unlockPurchase()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.buyButton.isEnabled = false
                    self.buyButton.alpha = 0.5
                    
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You For Your Purchase!", message: "The Unlimited Access Pass has successfully been bought.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
                
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
               
            default:
                break
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func unlockPurchase() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUnlimited")
    }
```

Comment: "Both devices are using the same sandbox account."  Doesn't that give you a ring as to what you should do?

Comment: I tried testing on a different account, but now, I get asked to sign in to the original account every time I open up the app.